# Is my .NET Core 3.1 app portable to .NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-5

I'm currently trying to port an ASP .NET Core 3.1 application to .NET 5.0.

In my app I use some 3rd party NuGet packages, which rely on .NET Core 3.1 and will not be ported to .NET 5.

Though I try to figure out if my application is fully portable to .NET 5.

In my app, I did the following steps:

- I updated the target framework in the `.csproj` file

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

- Then I updated all NuGet packages - it seems to work fine without errors.

Unfortunately I'm not sure, because in Solution Explorer => Project => Dependencies => Frameworks, I see the usage Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.NETCore.App.

[image]

My first question is, is it a problem to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.NETCore.App in the same .NET 5 app? What is the difference between those Frameworks?

- In a next step I run the .NET Portability Analyzer with target framework .NET 5.0 - the report says it is about 97% portable - but the dependent NuGets in .NET Core 3.1 cannot be altered.

My second question is, can I use .NET Core 3.1 NuGet packages in a .NET 5 application? I cannot change these 3rd party NuGet packages. It seems to work, but I thought it's not possible.

How can I verify if I can fully port my app from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5?

Comment: Note that .NET 5 is basically just ".NET Core 4", but with extra branding. It's fine to reference a library which targets an earlier version of .NET Core from an application which targets a later version

Comment: Here's a list of breaking changes when moving to `.net 5`, per microsoft - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0)

Comment: The whole Frameworks thing was introduced to avoid applications having to reference gazillions of NuGet packages (with different versions): they're centrally-installed collections of libraries. It's normal and expected that ASP.NET Core apps use both Microsoft.NETCore.App (which all (new) .NET Core apps will reference), and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (which contains the ASP.NET-specific libraries)

Comment: Also read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. Just upgrade all your project dependencies via NuGet to latest stable version and it will let you upgrade your .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 5. I have recently done on two projects working on. One of them is on Dev server working fine without any issue.

On hosting server you need to install .net 5 Hosting Bundle and restart the server... that's it